# How to set radio button checked to true on comparing it with textbox value?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, mysql

I am trying to set the radio checked out of two radio buttons using JavaScript on the basis of the textbox value.

The textbox can only be filled with the values of radio buttons only else both the radios will be checked false because the values will be coming from database.

```js
function selradio() {
  if (document.getElementById("tvt").value == '6 Wheeler') {
    document.getElementById('6wt').checked = true;
    document.getElementById('10wt').checked = false;
  } else if (document.getElementById("tvt").value == '10 Wheeler') {
    document.getElementById('6wt').checked = false;
    document.getElementById('10wt').checked = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="r3" value="6 Wheeler" class="flat-red"> 
    6 Wheeler Truck
  </label>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="r3" value="10 Wheeler" class="flat-red"> 
    10 Wheeler Truck
  </label>
</div>

<input type="text" id="tvt" name="tvt" onChange="selradio()">
```

Comment: Neither of your radio buttons have the `id` you specify in the JS. Fix that and it works. Voting to close as a typographical error.

Comment: Also note that the logic itself seems pointless. Select the values in the radios and get rid of the textbox. Alternatively use a `select` and highlight the relevant option based on what's in the DB

Comment: `<div class="col-sm-2">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="r3" id="6wt" value="6 Wheeler" class="flat-red"> 
    6 Wheeler Truck
  </label>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="r3" id="10wt" value="10 Wheeler" class="flat-red"> 
    10 Wheeler Truck
  </label>
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="col-sm-2">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" id="6wt" name="r3" value="6 Wheeler" class="flat-red"> 
    6 Wheeler Truck
  </label>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" id="10wt" name="r3" value="10 Wheeler" class="flat-red"> 
    10 Wheeler Truck
  </label>
</div>

<input type="text" id="tvt" name="tvt" onChange="selradio()">
```

Please set the **ID** of radio button and it will work.

Comment: Could you explain your answer? What is the problem and how did you fix it?